# Excel - VBA/Formula for checking duplicate (similar*) records using multiple conditions

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates, records

I'm looking for some help with this one. I need to check an Excel file with approx. 40000 records for similar records, according to multiple conditions. I also need this to be fairly foolproof for someone not entirely IT savvy to do regularly once shown how. Therefore, a macro or formula based solution would be preferred.

It seems easy enough to start with. Data has a header row with one record per row. It's easy enough to use conditional formatting to highlight rows with duplicate data in one or more columns, but I have an added complication.

Problem: I need to find records which have the same data in columns E and F (Surname and DOB), and I need the record to be highlighted as a duplicate if the dates in column K are similar (i.e. within 10 days of each other). Only if all 3 conditions are met would the record be highlighted as a potential duplicate.

Is this possible? I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Updated my function. Feel free to accpet the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function MATCHER(str1 As Range, rng1 As Range, str2 As String, rng2 As Range, num1 As Long, rng3 As Range, lim1 As Long)
Dim col(2) As Range, ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, str11 As String, FirstRow As Long, LastRow  As Long
MATCHER = False
Set ws = rng1.Worksheet                                                              'finds the worksheet of the first range (assumes all three ranges are on the same worksheet)
FirstRow = str1.Row + 1
LastRow = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row 'find the last row in the worksheet
Set rng = ws.Range("1:" & LastRow)                                                   'look down to the last row, inclusive
Set col(0) = Intersect(rng1.Columns, rng)                                            'apply the above criterion
Set col(1) = Intersect(rng2.Columns, rng)                                            'apply the above criterion
Set col(2) = Intersect(rng3.Columns, rng)                                            'apply the above criterion
For i = FirstRow To LastRow                                                          'from first to last row
If col(0)(i, 1).Value2 = str1.Value2 Then                                            'if the first range variable's first column's value in row equals the first string variable
    If col(1)(i, 1) = str2 Then                                                      'if the second range variable's first column's value in row equals the second string variable
        If col(2)(i, 1) >= num1 - lim1 And col(2)(i, 1) <= num1 + lim1 Then          'if the third range variable's first column's value in row equals the lookup value in confidence interval
            MATCHER = True                                                           'then it is true
            Exit Function                                                            'and there's no point in looking further
        End If
    End If
End If
Next
End Function
Sub ertdfgcvb()
x = MATCHER(Range("A1"), Range("A1"), "B", Range("B1"), 200, Range("C1"), 10)
MsgBox x
End Sub
```

For runtime considerations test in live environment. The first n-1 records will have the output *TRUE* where n = similar records.
It is meant to be used on a single recordset.

Comment: Note to self: It's even redundant. col(0)->rng1.Columns etc. 10 needs to be an optional(?) input variable. The ranges can be single cells.